# Linux kernel changelog for security features

Tags: kernel

I want to know what security features is added or improved in each Linux kernel release, is there anything like "security change log"?

I couldn't find it on the internet, the only thing I found is this: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/kernel-versions.md but it's for eBPF so it's not everything I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not aware of an “official” change log of security improvements in the Linux kernel, but Kees Cook sometimes publishes blog posts summarising improvements in a specific release. His latest post on the topic covers [security improvements in 5.10](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2022/04/04/security-things-in-linux-v5-10/) and has links to posts on earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, the article list in security category looks promising: https://outflux.net/blog/archives/category/security/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kees Cook, you could check less informative posts on the kernelnewbies.org website:

- [Security changes](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.18#Security) in Linux 5.18

I guess emailing Kees Cook and asking why he has stopped publishing updates could be a good idea.